# Almost empty pf.conf still logs packets

Tags: openbsd, pf, icmpv6

I have an issue that my pf logs many packets that it's not supposed to log. I reproduced it with almost empty pf.conf:

```
set skip on lo
```

and it still logs some packets. I think that all those packets have ICMP6 type and they do not really belong to my computer, I have no idea why am I receiving them, but I don't have control over it.

Here's example of packet (received with tcpdump on pflog0):

```
13:18:29.211678 rule def/(match) pass in on vio0: fe80::3ad5:47ff:fe75:1a2b > ff02::1:ff75:1a2b: HBH icmp6: multicast listener report  [hlim 1]
```

so my question is: where can I read about those default match rules and how do I disable those logs.

I tried to explicitly match those packets with something like `pass in on vio0` (without logging statement), but they are still logged, probably because of that mysterious default match which marks the packet to be logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea why am I receiving them

It's multicast traffic.

> where can I read about those default match rules

Well, the thing in whole is *partially documented* but it's not that obviously tracked back from the issue you're seeing.

[From `man pf.conf`](https://man.openbsd.org/pf.conf.5) (*markup* **is** mine):

> …
>
> *allow-opts* — *By default*, packets with IPv4 options or IPv6 **hop-by-hop** or destination options header *are blocked*. When allow-opts is specified for a pass rule, packets that pass the filter based on that rule (last matching) do so even if they contain options.
>
> …

— `HBH` you're seeing in logs is exactly that "hop-by-hop".

*My theory is:* Pf's developers decided that since that kind of traffic is to be blocked even if there's a `pass` rule (which seemingly is by default there in your case) it would make sense to whistle-blow harder, that's why you're getting it logged.

> and how do I disable those logs

As suggested in the man page you can fix that by introducing a `pass` rule with `allow-opts` explicitly given:

`pass allow-opts`